# TamperMonkey - Remove Table Row if Column Doesn't Contain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, tampermonkey

There's a website that I use for work (that still uses tables) which contains a number of rows in a table. I'm looking to delete rows in this table that don't contain "KEEP ME" in the second column. As you can see in the snippet below, the problem is that the contents aren't just in the TD, but they're contained in NOBR and then SPAN, within the TD.

```
<table id="T536870939" title="" class="BaseTable" style="width: 1879px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr tabindex="0" style=" color:#808000;" arrow="0">
            <td style="width: 155px;" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                <nobr class="dp " style="text-align: left; width: 155px;">
                    <span style="padding: 1px 4px;float:left;">Who cares?</span>
                </nobr>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 89px;" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                <nobr class="dp " style="text-align: left; width: 89px;">
                    <span style="padding: 1px 4px;float:left;">KEEP ME</span>
                </nobr>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 155px;" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                <nobr class="dp " style="text-align: left; width: 155px;">
                    <span style="padding: 1px 4px;float:left;">Who cares?</span>
                </nobr>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr tabindex="0" style=" color:#808000;" arrow="1">
            <td style="width: 155px;" class="BaseTableCell BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                <nobr class="dp " style="text-align: left; width: 155px;">
                    <span style="padding: 1px 4px;float:left;">Who cares?</span>
                </nobr>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 89px;" class="BaseTableCell BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                <nobr class="dp " style="text-align: left; width: 89px;">
                    <span style="padding: 1px 4px;float:left;">I'M BAD! DELETE ME!</span>
                </nobr>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 155px;" class="BaseTableCell BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                <nobr class="dp " style="text-align: left; width: 155px;">
                    <span style="padding: 1px 4px;float:left;">Who cares?</span>
                </nobr>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr tabindex="0" style=" color:#808000;" arrow="2">
            <td style="width: 155px;" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                <nobr class="dp " style="text-align: left; width: 155px;">
                    <span style="padding: 1px 4px;float:left;">Who cares?</span>
                </nobr>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 89px;" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                <nobr class="dp " style="text-align: left; width: 89px;">
                    <span style="padding: 1px 4px;float:left;">I'M ALSO BAD! PLEASE DELETE ME!</span>
                </nobr>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 155px;" class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText">
                <nobr class="dp " style="text-align: left; width: 155px;">
                    <span style="padding: 1px 4px;float:left;">Who cares?</span>
                </nobr>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried using the script below, but I am unsuccessful. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#T536870939 tr span:not([title!="KEEP ME"]):first').remove ();
```

Comment: `$('.BaseTable tr:not(:has(span:contains(KEEP ME)))').remove()`

Comment: I tried this, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: You're probably using old jQuery. Or the table is added to the page dynamically after the userscript has already run.

Comment: I created a test table html document, and it now works. It looks like the content is loaded after the fact... Or there's something else at play on the actual page.

Comment: Would this script not work if the table existed under layers and layers of divs?

Comment: See [Watch for element creation in greasemonkey script?](//stackoverflow.com/q/17632475)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I was worried that it wouldn't work with Chrome, because of the comments (saying that only woked with Firefox), but it does indeed work with Chrome. Thanks for your help. That works superbly.